# AEM Scheduler Needs to auto-start after Deployment

Tags: adobe, aem, aem-6

Need AEM scheduler code in a bundle to pick osgi configuration and start execute automatically as soon as bundle is deployed.
Currently after deploying the bundle with scheduler code in it, every time have to save configuration for respective scheduler to get it start.

Any pointers across it would be really appreciated.

Comment: Could you please update the question to make it more clear. What you are doing? What you are trying? What fails?

Comment: Have a scheduler code which needs to run every hour, provided cron expression accordingly. But after deployment of bundle scheduler wont start executing instead after configuration scheduler is opened and saved it starts executing.So every time need to open & save configuration of scheduler to start execute scheduler logic.

Comment: I will check this locally with me. But could you provide the OSGi component configuration of your scheduler (the class annotations)?

Comment: Find the Configuration details  @ObjectClassDefinition(name = "TestConfig",description = "TestConfig")
public @interface TestConfig {
@AttributeDefinition(name = "Name", type = AttributeType.STRING)
public String schedulerName() default "TestConfig";
@AttributeDefinition(name = "Enabled", type = AttributeType.BOOLEAN)
boolean serviceEnabled() default true;
@AttributeDefinition(name = "Cron Expression", type = AttributeType.STRING)
public String cronExpression() default "0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *";

Answer (score 0):

An Sling Scheduler Job is just a Runnable as OSGi-service. The Sling Scheduler Service will find all of them, and will trigger them according to their configuration (either with a cron-style or periodic).

https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/scheduler-service-commons-scheduler.html

*If you would like to use the Config-Class, please extend your question with your code (stripped down to the essentials, in your case the config and the scheduler job.*

Here is a working example. The Job runs every 5 seconds, as soon as the bundle is activated. No matter how the bundle is stopped/started or AEM is shutdown and restarted.

```
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Activate;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;

@Component(service = Runnable.class,
        property = {
                "scheduler.expression=*/5 * * * * ?"
        })
public class SchedulerTest implements Runnable {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass());

    public void run() {
        LOG.info("run");
    }

    @Activate
    protected void activate() {
        LOG.info("activated");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the demo scheduler provided in the project when one creates a new project using a multi module archetype. Below is a snippet from the same which defines the scheduler to run every 30 seconds. This can be modified in the system config.

```
@Designate(ocd=SimpleScheduledTask.Config.class)
@Component(service=Runnable.class)
public class SimpleScheduledTask implements Runnable {

    @ObjectClassDefinition(name="A scheduled task",
                           description = "Simple demo for cron-job like task with properties")
    public static @interface Config {

        @AttributeDefinition(name = "Cron-job expression")
        String scheduler_expression() default "*/30 * * * * ?";

        @AttributeDefinition(name = "Concurrent task",
                             description = "Whether or not to schedule this task concurrently")
```

Comment: When bundle is deployed for the 1st time, scheduler is disabled by default & code won’t execute. Enabling scheduler respective configuration it starts to execute logic.
Now again when same bundle is deployed for 2nd time, it is expecting the same scenario to save respective OSGI configuration to start execute even though scheduler is enabled.

Every time is it required to save Config when bundle is deployed ?

Answer (score 0):

We faced the same issue and honestly I think all the examples aren't clear enough what you should do in the case you describe.

So what we did to solve the issue was to annotate one method with @Activate
and @Modified (respectively do the same thing on activation and on modification):

```
@Activate
@Modified
protected void activate(SchedulerConfiguration config) {
    killScheduler();
    schedulerID = config.name().hashCode();
    addScheduler(config);
}
```

The rest goes like in all the examples you can find (e.g. [this one](https://aem.redquark.org/2018/10/day-13-schedulers-in-aem.html)).